# AST Browser in Intellij

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

Is there anyway I can open the AST Browser in Intellij for a Grails project? I am trying to figure out the compilation phases for various gorm objects and services.

Comment: The Groovy console has a nice AST browser available. Use the `console` command for Grails to launch the console.

Comment: Yes I know.  But i want to see the AST for my grails services and gorm objects as they are.

Comment: And those will be available there (: The Groovy console launches your Grails app. So it's fully setup and ready to be used from there. `ctx` is a quick pointer to the application context. You can use all your domain classes, services, etc. from within the console, and the AST browser too.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not using the AST Browser in Intellij but the AST browser that comes with the Groovy console is quite handy.

Using the `console` command from your Grails application will launch the console with your Grails application fully setup and running. Within the console you can access all of your Grails application and the AST browser.

`ctx` within the console gives you a quick handle to the main application context so you can get a reference to any service/bean within your application. GORM and everything else is also available too.